# Support for PHP 7.4? in Propel 1.7.x?

Tags: propel

I upgraded to php7.4 on my dev box and am receiving a lot of deprecated errors with Propel 1.7.2. I see there is a closed thread in the support channel indicating fixes are in master, but they sure haven't made it to Propel 1.7.3 at http://propelorm.org/Propel/download.html. Does anyone know if/when the Propel folks are going to release a 1.7.x that is compatible with php74 (php 7.4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't expeced to much from propel. The Project is more or less dead as of March 21.

As of their official github-page propel1 is  outdated and unmaintained. See: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel

> Current stable (and outdated and unmaintained) version of Propel -
> Please use v2 https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2

Propel2 on the other hand is still in alpha. See: http://propelorm.org/download.html

> Note: The version 2 of Propel is still under development. Please visit
> http://propelorm.org/Propel/ if you want to use a stable version.

There is also Propel3. Which is not even in alpha yet. See: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel3

> Propel3 is an open-source Object-Relational Mapping (ORM) for modern
> PHP 7.1+. Version 3 of Propel ORM replaces Propel2, which is not
> maintained anymore.

Maybe also see the discussion here: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel3/issues/92